# Unable to open some apps from iOS 12 Shortcuts

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

In the iOS 12 Shortcuts app, I'd like to build a shortcut that opens a specific app. This app doesn't have any specific integration with Shortcuts, but it's sufficient to just have the system open the app. So I added an "Open App" action to the end of my workflow — but the app I want to open does not appear in the list of choices for the Open App action.

I noticed that a small fraction of apps on my phone are missing from the Open App list. It seems pretty random: Apple Pages is missing but Keynote is not, some but not all games are missing, etc.

Is there some reason that I cannot open certain apps via Shortcuts?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the "Open URL" action to open the app using URL schemes.

You can find some URL schemes by doing a Google search for it([here's](https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/3mux7h/ios_url_schemes/) a good list).

If you can't find it online, you can get it manually(you need a computer):

1. Download the `.ipa` of the app you want to get the URL schemes of(you can use iTunes)
2. Rename it from `.ipa` to `.zip` and extract it
3. Open the `Payload` folder
4. Right click on the application inside and chose "Show Package Contents"(or just open the .app folder if you're not on Mac)
5. Open the `Info.plist` file and look for "URL Schemes".

Comment: do not forget to Up Vote the OP if the question been asked was clear.

Comment: This is a useful workaround in some but not all cases. Some of the apps that don't appear for me in the "Open App" list in Shortcuts do not support custom URL schemes.